# Adding Rectangle to a JPanel

Tags: java, rectangles

So basically I´m trying to add some Rectangles to a JPanel. This specific Rectangle also have methods that change the visibility and color. But when these Rectangles are added nothing happens.

Here´s the class for the Rectangles:

```java
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Rectangle extends JPanel {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    private static int Width = 30;
    private static int Height = 30;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 0));
        g.drawRect(x, y, Width, Height);
    }

    public Rectangle(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void changeColor() {
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 0));
        repaint();
    }

    public void changeVisibility() {
        setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

And here´s the method that adds the Recangles to the JPanel in the Frame class:

```java
 public void placeRectangle(int x, int y) {
     Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle(x, y);
     panel.add(newRasenblock);
     newRect.setVisible(true);
 }
```

I´ve tested this method with the Rectangles (without the `changeColor` and `changeVisibility`) before and it worked there, but here with similar code, it suddenly doesn´t.

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding `newRect` in your method?  What is `newRasenblock`?  It would also help if you showed a simple example calling the method.

Comment: Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. Also, don't call your class  "Rectangle" there is an AWT class by that name so it is confusing. Your class name should be more specific.

Comment: Note, when you call `drawRect` inside of paintComponent, the coordinates are going to be relative to where the JPanel is. So if you want your JPanel to be the size of the rectangle, then drawRect should be at (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example adding to a JFrame.  You don't really need to override paintComponent unless you plan on doing more graphics.

Note:  x and y aren't being used here.  I would suggest you rely on a layout manager to position your rectangles as opposed to absolute positioning.

And I don't understand what subclassing JPanel offers as opposed to just using a JPanel itself?

```
public class RectangleDemo {
    
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->new RectangleDemo().start());
    }
    
    public void start() {
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        f.pack();
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        placeRectangle(10,10);
    }
    
    public void placeRectangle(int x, int y) {
        Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle(x, y);
        f.add(newRect);
        
        newRect.setVisible(true);
        f.repaint();
    }
}

class Rectangle extends JPanel {
    
    private int x;
    private int y;
    
    private static int Width = 100;
    private static int Height = 100;
    
    
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(Width, Height);
    }
    public Rectangle(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        setPreferredSize(getPreferredSize());
        changeColor();
    }
    
    public void changeColor() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0,102,0),2));
        repaint();
    }
    
    public void changeVisibility() {
        setVisible(false);
    }
}
```